# how to install g++ 4 on CentOS 8

Tags: g++, centos8

Have some legacy C++ software that can only be compiled using g++ 4. How to install g++ 4 on CentOS 8 machine?
Found a lot of references to upgrade g++ in CentOS 6/7. But CentOS 8 seems totally different. E.g. can't find ways to access centos-release-scl and devtoolset-4 yum package.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for the legacy software issue.

Used the new default g++ compiler with option: `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=gnu++98`

The resulting objects are ABI compatible with old libraries.